# Raku exceptions: why are errors thrown sometime after the code that caused the errors?

Tags: raku

This seems crazy to me:

```
use v6.d;

say "Before division by zero!";
my $result = divide(3, 0);
say "After division by zero!";

sub divide($a, $b) {
    my $result;
    $result = $a / $b;  # Line 11
    return $result;
}

sub go($x) {
    say "hello";
    say $x;             # Line 17
}

go($result);            # Line 20

--output:--
Before division by zero!
After division by zero!
hello
Attempt to divide by zero when coercing Rational to Str
  in sub go at b.raku line 17
  in block <unit> at b.raku line 20
```

The error says to look at line 17.  Yet, the error is from line 11.

In perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{say};
use Data::Dumper;


say "Before division by zero!";
my $result = divide(3, 0);
say "After division by zero!";

sub divide {
    my ($a, $b) = @_; 
    my $result = $a / $b;    # Line 13
    return $result;
}

sub go {
    my ($x) = @_;
    say "hello";
    say $x;
}

go(20, 30);

--output:--
Before division by zero!
Illegal division by zero at a.pl line 13.
```

The perl program produces an error that points to the code that actually caused the error.

Furthermore, in raku you can't even use a try block to contain the error:

```
sub divide($a, $b) {
    my $result;

    try {
        $result = $a / $b; 
    }

    return $result;
}
```

That produces the same output as the raku program above.

Why did raku decide that:

> When dealing with an exception, the place where the exception is "used"
> determines when it's thrown.

...where "used" seems to mean output with say()?  As you can see from my example, it makes it difficult to figure out where the error is in your code.  Does that have to do with lazy evaluation?

Comment: *When dealing with an exception, the place where the exception is "used" determines when it's thrown.* You've formatted that as a quote. It's absolutely wrong at many basic levels. Is it from doc? Or some other place we can control and/or correct? If so, where?

Comment: My initial google for that quote failed. But today I decided to fiddle and have now found the matching quote [here](https://uzluisf.gitlab.io/raku-by-example/exceptions/) in "Raku by Example". What the page says (and hence your Q too) contain multiple basic errors. If you poke around you'll see that the article's source is stored on gitlab. I know *of* gitlab, but not how to post an issue corresponding to the source. (I'm not going to compose a PR because that's the wrong solution.) Does anyone know the norms for bringing some issue to the attention of an author of gitlab source?

Comment: String interpolation performs "use" of a variable without printing anything. So `my $result = divide(3, 0); "{$result}";` appears to produce the desired result. Maybe there's a more elegant way that I overlooked.

Comment: For your further research, I suggest looking at the docs for [Exception](https://docs.raku.org/type/Exception), [Failure](https://docs.raku.org/type/Failure), and [fatal](https://docs.raku.org/language/pragmas#fatal). Although ZDRs are not Failures, many other cases of a "deferred throw" are. And as noted, exceptions are not *in general* deferred.

Answer (score 2):

This question reiterates this example from a popular "[Raku by Example](https://uzluisf.gitlab.io/raku-by-example/exceptions/)" course. That course explains the situation like this:

> These last two code snippets illustrate the mechanism of failing softly allowed by Raku. In short, this means that exceptions aren't thrown until the value associated with them is about to be used. And this is what happens in these code snippets; the exceptions are only thrown when the value from divide(3,0) is used.

This reference is not provided accurately or in context.

The last part of the question asks of this statement "why did Raku decide that"... but the original reference already answers this.

Comment: "*This [...] question [...] should be closed by the moderators*": For what reason? It is on-topic, perfectly clear and has a reproducible example. If you believe it should be closed, why did you even answer it in the first place? Why not vote to close?

Comment: Perhaps the question can be improved by providing the reference?

Comment: Actually, in this case the "problem" is that `N / 0` is a `Rat`, and it won't actually throw an error unless it is actually being used as a value.  And even **then** it produces a `Failure`, and when that is being used as a value, will it throw at the location where it was being used as a value.